# compare dates in two different columns of two dataframes and return count of upcoming date

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, dataframe

Consider two date columns (Pandas dataframe)
YYYY - MM - DD

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : ['2017-10-06','2017-11-15','2017-11-05','2018-10-06']}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : ['2017-10-06','2017-10-06','2018-12-05','2017-10-17','2019-10-06','2017-12-05','2017-3-30']})
```

df1:

```
          col1
0    2017-10-06
1    2017-11-15
2    2017-11-05
3    2018-10-06
```

Name: col1, dtype: object

df2:

```
    col1
0   2017-10-06
1   2017-10-06
2   2018-12-05
3   2017-10-17
4   2019-10-06
5   2017-12-05
6   2017-3-30
```

Note :
This is an imbalanced column

Now i should return the count of each date value in df1 that has how many upcoming date count  than df2 col1 date columns

Output:

```
df1
       col1     count upcoming in df2 col1
0   2017-10-06  4
1   2017-11-15  3
2   2017-11-05  2
3   2018-10-06  2
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: pandas from excel

Comment: why 2017-10-06 is 3 rather than 4

Comment: Thanks  @Wen for pointing out it should be 4. Thanks for pointing out i changed now

Comment: Also why 2018-10-06 is 4 rather than 2

Answer (score 1):

Here is method from `numpy`

```
df1['count']=(df1.col1.values[:,None]<df2.col1.values).sum(1)
df1
Out[423]: 
        col1  count
0 2017-10-06      4
1 2017-11-15      3
2 2017-11-05      3
3 2018-10-06      2
```

Comment: I get memory error for the above on using it.
I checked online and i am using 64bit python also have enought ram 7gb ram for the process.
Any suggestions or alternatives

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: @Dux 
I applied for millions rows against a million